# Jquery - Add img title to thumbnails

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm having problems grabbing the title tag from an image in a slider and inserting it somewhere else on my page. It's only grabbing the first title from the first image and not the subsequent ones.

My script:

```
var imgTitle = $('.nivoSlider img').attr('title')

$('a.nivo-control').append('<p>' + (imgTitle) + '</p>');
```

I know I have to use .each someplace but I don't know where.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get an array of titles.  Then use the index parameter in your call to `.each()` to get the corresponding title:

```
var titles = $('.nivoSlider img').map(function() {
    return this.title;
}).get();
$('a.nivo-control').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append("<p>" + titles[i] + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been driving me up the wall. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user96 - My pleasure.  By the way, if my answer did the trick, please remember to accept/upvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example:

```
$('.nivoSlider img').each( function() {
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

I think you will get all the images title attributes